# Redis client in C#: saturating the pipe?

Tags: c#, .net, redis

I have several components in my C# code reading and setting key/value pairs in Redis in a multi-threaded context. The following minimal example

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

//Uncomment one of these two
//using CSRedis;
using Sider;

namespace FailureTesting
{
    class UsingRedis
    {
        static RedisClient client = new RedisClient("localhost");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread read = new Thread(Reader);
            Thread set = new Thread(Setter);

            read.Start();
            set.Start();
        }

        static void Reader()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                client.Get("key");
            }
        }

        static void Setter()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                client.Set("key", "value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

throws an Unhandled exception with `Additional information: Expecting a Bulk reply, got instead`69`reply` which makes me think that the pipe between C# and Redis is saturated. This occurs wether I use CSRedis or Sider.

On the other hand, if I use a second client, that is a second pipe for the Setter method, then everything works fine (setting `static RedisClient client2 = new RedisClient("localhost");` and then `client2.Set(...)`)

Finally, using the StackExchange.Redis library with the following equivalent code

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

using StackExchange.Redis;
namespace FailureTesting
{
    class TestingSider
    {
        static IDatabase db = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379").GetDatabase();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread read = new Thread(Reader);
            Thread set = new Thread(Setter);

            read.Start();
            set.Start();
        }

        static void Reader()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                db.StringGet("key");
            }
        }

        static void Setter()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                db.StringSet("key", "value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then everything works well. The problem I have is that the StackExchange library is only supported by .NET Framework 4.5 while I have to use .Net Framework 4.0.

Could someone give me some insights about what happens here? I don't want to put locks or mutex in my code while Redis guarantees that all the operations are atomic...

Comment: StackExchange.Redis supports both .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Also redis has `Transactions` !